# UIButton title "Button" is not cleared after removing it from the attribute inspector

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, swift5, xcode13

I cleared the title from attribute inspector, but while running the app, text "Button" is displaying.
[image: UIButton Attribute inspector]

Output:

[image]

I checked different scenarios and the issue occurs only if the deployment target is below 15.0

Is there any solution for this?.

Xcode Version: 13.0
Project deployment target: 13.4

Comment: See this topic.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69375584/xcode-13-button-title-not-disappearing

Comment: both are same, the issue occurs when the deployment target is less than 15.0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change the button style from plain to default.

[image]

Comment: Keep the button type to custom if you don't want to change image color to system(blue)

Answer (score 48):

Change the button style to "Default"
[For more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjy9Y.png)

Comment: The default button style isn't Default. Love it

Comment: If you're using an image without text, eg the system mic image, changing to default completely squashes the image. :(